# Converting XML Clob using XMLtable/Xpath and storing it in Database table

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle10g, extract, xmltable

I am trying to extract below XMl into rows and column using Oracle Pl/SQL, but not getting it in desired format

XML:-

```
<QualificationCriterion name="iPass Roaming Zone 1" description="" id="##PC4.0##183647208" status="CheckedIn" kind="Implementation" eventName="##PC4.0##67625472">
    <Condition xsi:type="LogicalExpression" expressionType="AND" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Operands>
            <Operand xsi:type="LogicalExpression" expressionType="AND">
                <Operands>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="NE" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Service filter"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="ValueRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" name="Pseudo Allowance "/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##76915825" entity="Customer" entityName="##PC4.0##701" attributeName="Last BLIMPACT Cycle Month"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="ValueRef" type="##PC4.0##76915825" name="Wholesale"/>
                    </Operand>
                </Operands>
            </Operand>
            <Operand xsi:type="LogicalExpression" expressionType="OR">
                <Operands>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="23102"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="21630"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="26201"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="23001"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="23203"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="20420"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##8537479" value="23207"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##6250817" value="21901"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##6250817" value="20416"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6250817" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Provider ID"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="Constant" type="##PC4.0##6250817" value="22004"/>
                    </Operand>
                </Operands>
            </Operand>
            <Operand xsi:type="LogicalExpression" expressionType="OR">
                <Operands>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Service filter"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="ValueRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" name="ROAMBL"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Service filter"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="ValueRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" name="ROAMGP"/>
                    </Operand>
                    <Operand xsi:type="Comparison" expressionType="EQ" type="Boolean">
                        <LeftOperand xsi:type="AttributeRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" entity="Event" entityName="##PC4.0##67625472" attributeName="Service filter"/>
                        <RightOperand xsi:type="ValueRef" type="##PC4.0##6249415" name="GPRSRM"/>
                    </Operand>
                </Operands>
            </Operand>
        </Operands>
    </Condition>
</QualificationCriterion>
```

Expected OutPut :-

> NAME    value1  value2  value4 iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter 
>   Pseudo Allowance    AND iPass Roaming Zone 1    Last BLIMPACT Cycle
>   Month   Wholesale   AND iPass Roaming Zone 1             iPass Roaming
>   Zone 1    Provider ID 23102   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID
>   21630   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 26201   OR iPass
>   Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 23001   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Provider ID 23203   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 20420   OR
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 23207   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Provider ID 21901   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 20416   OR
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID 22004   OR iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter  ROAMBL  OR iPass Roaming Zone
>   1    Service filter  ROAMGP  OR iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter
>   GPRSRM  OR

And What i have got till now,

> NAME    value1  value2  value3  value4 iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   AND iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter           iPass Roaming
>   Zone 1        Pseudo Allowance         iPass Roaming Zone 1    Last
>   BLIMPACT Cycle Month            iPass Roaming Zone 1        Wholesale 
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1                OR iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1            23102    iPass
>   Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   21630    iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID          iPass Roaming
>   Zone 1            26201    iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1            23001    iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1            23203    iPass
>   Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   20420    iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID          iPass Roaming
>   Zone 1            23207    iPass Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1            21901    iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1            20416    iPass
>   Roaming Zone 1    Provider ID          iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   22004    iPass Roaming Zone 1                OR iPass Roaming Zone 1
>   Service filter           iPass Roaming Zone 1        ROAMBL
>   iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter           iPass Roaming Zone 1 
>   ROAMGP       iPass Roaming Zone 1    Service filter           iPass
>   Roaming Zone 1        GPRSRM

My Code :-

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM   (select * from pc_element where element_type='QualificationCriterion' and name='ETDR Group' and first_effective_version is not null and last_effective_version is null) x,
       XMLTABLE('/QualificationCriterion/Condition | //Operand[not(@type="Boolean")] | //Operands/Operand/LeftOperand | //Operands/Operand/RightOperand'
         PASSING x.xmltype(element_value)
         COLUMNS
        -- "value0"    VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@expressionType',
           "value1"    VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@attributeName',
           "value2" varchar2(10) PATH '@name',
            "value3" varchar2(10) PATH '@value',
            "value4"    VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@expressionType'
         ) xt ;
```

For every value extracting , i am getting 3 blank space and that value in a row please help, i am new in XML parsing and very confused, please help

Comment: @PrashantMishra : updated it

Comment: @PrashantMishra My Code is also added

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you need:

```
SELECT xt.NAME NAME, xt.attributeName value1, nvl(RName,RValue) value2, xt.expressionType value4
FROM   (select * from pc_element where element_type='QualificationCriterion' and name='ETDR Group' and first_effective_version is not null and last_effective_version is null) x,
   --XMLTABLE('/QualificationCriterion/Condition | //Operands/Operand[not(@type="Boolean")] | //Operands/Operand/LeftOperand | //Operands/Operand/RightOperand'
   XMLTABLE('//Operand[@type="Boolean"]' 
     PASSING x.xmltype(element_value)
     COLUMNS
       NAME   VARCHAR2(50) PATH './../../../../../@name',
       attributeName    VARCHAR2(50) PATH './LeftOperand/@attributeName',
       RName varchar2(50) PATH './RightOperand/@name',
        RValue varchar2(50) PATH './RightOperand/@value',
        expressionType    VARCHAR2(50) PATH './../../@expressionType'
        --"self"    varchar2(50) path 'name()'
     ) xt ;
```

Comment: :- Thanks a lot , almost what is need, But not getting the NAME and value4 column values :-(

Comment: Try increasing or reducing number of `../` depending on the location of @name attribute. Do the similar thing to value4 also.